# Error while converting date string to date

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic, ora-01858

In my project in my_table time of any event is stored in number format. Now I have to convert it to oracle datetime format.

Here is an explanation below:

**Example1 :**
•Sched_Arr_Tm = 0450, will equal 04:30 am (the first 2 is HH (24 hour clock.  Since 04 < 12, then just use that number as the hour))  and the next 2 are the fractional equivalent of an hour (.50 * 60 min = 30 min)

•Sched_Arr_Tm = 2100, will equal 9:00 PM (since 21> 12, then take 21-12=9)

•Sched_Arr_Tm = 1475, will equal 02:45 Pm (the first 2 is HH (24 hour clock.  Since 14 > 12. Then take 14-12=2), then just use that number as the hour)) and the next 2 are the fractional equivalent of an hour (.75 * 60 min = 45 min)

•Sched_Arr_Tm = 0075, will equal 12:45 AM (since the hour = 00, then the hour= 12) and the next 2 are the fractional equivalent of an hour (.75 * 60 min = 45 min)

I am able to extract data according to above login but getting error while converting it to date.

```
select sched_arr_tm,
    LPAD(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm, 1,length(tn.sched_arr_tm) - 2),2,'0') as HH,
    RPAD(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,3,length(tn.sched_arr_tm) - 2)) * .60,0),2,'0') as MM,
    '00' AS SS,
    LPAD(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,1,length(tn.sched_arr_tm) - 2),2,'0')
    ||':' ||
    RPAD(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,3,length(tn.sched_arr_tm) - 2)) * .60,0),2,'0') 
    ||':'||
    LPAD(0,2,0) AS DTTM,
    TO_DATE(LPAD(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,1,length(tn.sched_arr_tm) - 2),2,'0')
          ||':' ||
           RPAD(TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(substr(tn.sched_arr_tm,3,length(tn.sched_arr_tm) - 2)) * .60,0),2,'0') 
          ||':'|| 
           LPAD(00,2,0),'HH24:MI:SS') AS DTTM,
   tn.sched_slip_arr_tm
```

from MY_TABLE;

I am getting this error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with:

```
SQL> with data as (select 450 Sched_Arr_Tm from dual
  2                union all
  3                select 1475 from dual
  4                union all
  5                select 2100 from dual)
  6  select Sched_Arr_Tm, to_date(hours||':'||(60*(mins/100)), 'hh24:mi')
  7    from (select Sched_Arr_Tm, substr(Sched_Arr_Tm, -2) mins,
  8                substr(Sched_Arr_Tm, 1, length(Sched_Arr_Tm)-2) hours
  9            from data)
 10  /

SCHED_ARR_TM TO_DATE(HOURS||':
------------ -----------------
         450 01-jan-2013 04:30
        1475 01-jan-2013 14:45
        2100 01-jan-2013 21:00

SQL>
```